Bug - I think - with the Contact Reference field type when it is multiselect
We ran into this problem today after updating to 5.78.4, and I confirmed that it is happening the same way on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/
If you create a custom field of type Contact Reference and have it be multiselect, if you try to submit the form without any value in the field you get an error. Having a user or multiple users there it works fine, but without it I get:
CRM_Core_Exception:  is not of type String in vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO.php on line 1732


Might be the same as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5555 ?

That looks like it exactly, thank you! I looked there, but didn't find it.
